# SQL query using set operation? Question:Find the staffno of all staffs that have handled properties of type ‘house’ and ‘flat’ in the same city

Tags: sql, union

I am using Dreamhome database. This is my query:

select (staffno) from propertyforrent where staffno in(
select staffno from propertyforrent 
where type ='House'
union
select staffno from propertyforrent 
where type ='Flat'
)and city= 'Glasgow'[image]

I have tried this. But it's wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Use aggregation:

```
select distinct staffno
from t
where type in ('House', 'Flat')
group by staffno, city
having count(distinct type) = 2;
```

This is one of the very few cases where `select distinct` is used with `group by`.  You are not asking for the city, so this just returns the staff number, even if there are multiple cities.

Comment: Hi, thank you! But how to apply set operation like union or intersect in this question?

Comment: @Yumi . . . Huh?  This answers your question.